# How to add product sorting dropdown in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I saw a lot of questions on stackoverflow about removing this dropdown. I want to ADD IT on my theme and it doesn't work.

I tried adding this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_catalog_ordering', 10 );
```

aaand didn't work.

What's the catch? I already have in my archive-product.php this piece of code:

```
<?php
 /**
 * woocommerce_before_shop_loop hook
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_result_count - 20
 * @hooked woocommerce_catalog_ordering - 30
 */
 do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' );
?>
```

So the sorting template is included, right? Where am I messing this up?

Comment: You have to add woocomerce product sorting dropdown widgets to sidebar from admin under appearance.

Comment: Don't have a sidebar on the archive-product.php, only on the actual product page. My layout looks similar to this one: https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/19270/screenshots/1901704/15_pco2.jpg except I don't have a sorting dropdown menu.

Comment: Have you checked to see if its not hidden using some CSS? Does you theme have a `woocommerce/loop/orderby.php` file ?

Comment: Found the solution. The css class responsible for the dropdown form had a display:none :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution thanks to Anand. the .woocommerce-ordering class had a display:none on it.

Comment: Thanks for the hint :) In my case "select" tag was set to `display:none;`. Used inspection tool to figure out which is set to hidden.

Answer (score 3):

First add this to your functions.

```
<?php 
 // sorting
 remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_catalog_ordering', 30 );
 add_action( 'woo_custom_catalog_ordering', 'woocommerce_catalog_ordering', 30 ); 
?>
```

Then wherever you want to have the sort box just drop it in.

```
<?php do_action( 'woo_custom_catalog_ordering' ); ?>
```